# React.js setState not not notifying

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple todo list with React.js and I'm stuck with this problem. `todo.isChecked` is seting the state, but the new style determined by it doesn't notify just after clicking on the checkbox, but if I type something in the input text.

```
import React from 'react';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import 'jquery';
import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';

import TodoItem from './todoItem'

export default class todoApp extends React.Component{
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.state = {
            todos: [],
            task: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
        this.handleText = this.handleText.bind(this)
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    }

    handleChange(id) {
        const todos = this.state.todos
        todos.map( todo => todo.id === id ? todo.isChecked === false ? todo.isChecked = true : todo.isChecked = false : null )
        console.log(this.state.todos)
     }

    handleText(event){
        this.setState( {task: event.target.value} )
    }

    handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault()
        const task = this.state.task.trim()
        if (task.length > 0){
            const id = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 9)
            const newTask = { task: task, isChecked: false, id: id }
            const todos = this.state.todos
            todos.push(newTask)
            this.setState({ 
                todos: todos,
                task: ''
            })
        }
    }

    render(){
        const todoItems = this.state.todos.map(item => <TodoItem key={item.id} item={item} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>)

        return(
        <div class="card bg-dark shadow-lg p-3 mb-5 rounded" style={{width: '18rem'}}>
            <form onSubmit={ this.handleSubmit } id="form">
                <input 
                    type="text" onChange={ this.handleText } 
                    value={ this.state.task } placeholder="New Task" 
                />
                <input type="submit" />
            </form>
            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                <li class="list-group-item bg-dark">{todoItems}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

todoItem.js:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function TodoItem(props) {
    const isCheckedStyle = {
        fontstyle: "italic",
        color: "#adad85",
        textDecoration:"line-through"
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                onChange={() => props.handleChange(props.item.id)}
            />
            <p style={props.item.isChecked ? isCheckedStyle : null} >{props.item.task}</p>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: you're not using `setState(...)` in the function that is called when checkbox is changed

Answer (score 0):

```
 handleChange(id) {
        const todos = this.state.todos
        todos.map( todo => todo.id === id ? todo.isChecked === false ? todo.isChecked = true : todo.isChecked = false : null )
        console.log(this.state.todos)
     }
```

Your're directly modifying the `todo.isChecked` without `setState`. When you do so, React doesn't have a way to know the state is changed and re-render has to take place. So instead modify using `setSate()`

Answer (score 0):

In both `handleChange` and `handleSubmit` you mutating state outside `setState`, which is illegal in React, on `handleChange` you haven't even called `setState`, so just change it to (and so on `handleSubmit`)

```
 handleChange(id) {
        const todos = [...this.state.todos].map( todo => todo.id === id ? { ...todo, isChecked: !todo.isChecked } : todo ) // adding [...  ] for shallow copy and not pointing
        this.setState({todos})
  }
```